# Is it possible to easily change the paging behavior of the Display License Agreement Screen in install4j?

Tags: install4j

In console mode, the "Display License Agreement Screen" separates the license text into pages, with the only option being to hit "Enter" through each page.  How can I customize this behavior and add something like a "(Q)uit" for people that have seen the license agreement 1000 times and just want to accept it.

Do I have to write custom screen code of some sort?  Or is there a better way?  If no, can this be added as a feature request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

- Add a "Configurable form" before the "Display license" screen
- Set the "Condition expression" of the new screen to `context.isConsole()`
- Add a "Console handler" form component to the new screen and set its script to:

  ```
  if (!console.askYesNo("Show license?")) {
      context.goForward(2, true, true);
  }
  return true;
  ```

Then the display license screen will only bee shown if the user confirms this question.

Comment: OK, I'll have to run that by legal to see if it's an acceptable work around. Helps a lot for testing, thanks for that. Is this the only option? If I had to implement my own screen, perhaps subclassing what's there and just overriding the prompt, is that possible/easy?

Comment: @Frank Yes, you can extend `com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.LicenseScreen` and override `public boolean handleConsole(Console console)`.